# What is the hotkey combo for the Action Star Linxcel US-146A KVM Switch

Tags: hotkeys, kvm-switch

This is a (very) old 4 port USB/VGA KVM switch that I do not have the manual for.  I was able to use search engines to look up some details about it.  A picture can be seen on [this page](http://www.suntekpc.com/htm-2/data-switch-kvm-xxx-linxcel-us-146a-us146a.htm) or [here](http://venus.morante.net/downloads/unibia/other/US146A/) in case it becomes unavailable.

I believe the KVM switch is from the early 2000's.  It goes by the model DS-KVM-02-US146A.  According to the info I have found so far it's made by a company called LinXcel.  USB probing identifies it as an Action Star KVM.

The switch supposedly has a hotkey combination that lets you switch the inputs, but I am unable to find any mention of it.  I tried contacting the manufacture but got no response.  It seems they have been out of the KVM business for a few years and have no interest in supporting this old hardware.

This question is directed towards anyone who has worked with this specific model and knows exactly what the hotkey combo is.  Please don't suggest the 'typical' combos unless you are certain it is the correct one.  I've already tried countless combinations with no success.

I tried the usual 2x <kbd>ScrLk</kbd>, 3x <kbd>ScrLk</kbd> with <kbd>ENTER</kbd> or <kbd>1</kbd>-<kbd>4</kbd>, arrows. <kbd>NumLk</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> and <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, then <kbd>1</kbd>-<kbd>4</kbd>, or arrows

Comment: KVM's commonly use Scroll Lock twice in quick succession. Or scroll lock twice, then a number or the right cursor key? You don't say which combos you have tried, so I have to ask. Others will do the same, so perhaps list the common combos you've tried...

Comment: I tried the usual 2x ScrLk, 3x ScrLk with ENTER or 1-4, arrows.  NumLk, CTRL+ALT+SHFT and ENTER, then 1-4, or arrows.  Pretty much any combo that would show up on a Google search for any other KVM switch.